# can't sync Calendar events from Mac to iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, data-synchronization, calendar

Mac running OS X 10.8.1, and iPhone 4 running 5.1.1. Since upgrading to OS X 10.8.1 from 10.7.4, I can't sync Calendar events from the Mac to the iPhone. The opposite direction works just fine. I am using iTunes for the sync via USB, all calendars are checked in iTunes to be synced.

Any idea what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after looking at some error entries in `system.log` I found a link to this Apple KB article: [Mac OS X: Resetting the SyncServices folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1627), which solved my problem. It is important not only to reset the sync services, but also to enable them after that as shown at the end of the KB article.